# I want to customize Xamarin MasterDetail (Xamarin Crossplatform project)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, master-detail

Just check the image below. I want to change the color of marked areas on the Image. The image is a screenshot of UWP application developed using **xamarin forms cross platform project** **(PCL)**. 
I am using MasterDetail page navigation.

[image]

Now Color is changed as per my first requirement.

**Now what I want is a screen design like below**[image]

**Now I am getting a result as below**[image: result of first screen]
Result of second screen ie, after navigating to stock entry page 
[image: Result of second screen ie, after navigating to stock entry page]

**Source Code**

**1. MasterDetailsPage.Xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GST.Views.MasterDetailsPage"
             Title="Stock Manager"

                  MasterBehavior="SplitOnPortrait"
              BackgroundColor="#0063b1"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:GST.Views;assembly=GST">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master >
        <pages:MasterDetailsPageMaster  x:Name="MasterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>

        <NavigationPage >
      <x:Arguments>
        <pages:GST_Home  />

      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage> 
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

**2. MasterDetailsPage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace GST.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MasterDetailsPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MasterDetailsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;           
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterDetailsPageMenuItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;



            var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
            Detail.Title = item.Title;


            IsPresented = false;

             Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page);

            MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;

        }
    }
}
```

**3. MasterDetailsPageDetail.xaml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GST.Views.MasterDetailsPageDetail"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Key=background-color}"
               Title="Master GST Title Detailed" >
  <StackLayout Padding="10">
    <Label Text="This is a detail page. To get the 'triple' line icon on each platform add a icon to each platform and update the 'Master' page with an Icon that references it."/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**4.MasterDetailsPageDetail.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace GST.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MasterDetailsPageDetail : ContentPage
    {
        public MasterDetailsPageDetail()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           // NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
            // NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        }
    }
}
```

**5. MasterDetailsPageMaster.xaml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GST.Views.MasterDetailsPageMaster"

             Title="Home">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenuItems"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
      <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#03A9F4">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Text="AppName"
              Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
      </ListView.Header>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    FontSize="24"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**6.MasterDetailsPageMaster.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace GST.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MasterDetailsPageMaster : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView => ListViewMenuItems;

        public MasterDetailsPageMaster()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ViewModels.MasterDetailsPageMasterViewModel();

        }

    }
}
```

**7.MasterDetailsPageMenuItem.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GST.Views
{

    public class MasterDetailsPageMenuItem
    {
        public MasterDetailsPageMenuItem()
        {
            TargetType = typeof(MasterDetailsPageDetail);
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**8.GST_Home.xaml     -- Home Dash**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             Title="Home Dash"
             x:Class="GST.Views.GST_Home">

    <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <Label Text="This is a detail page. To get the 'triple' line icon on each platform add a icon to each platform and update the 'Master' page with an Icon that references it."/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**9.GST_Home.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace GST.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class GST_Home : ContentPage
    {
        public GST_Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want full source code please refer my code which is uploaded on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2XtD2dQvEhzb1NnNGdydG91S0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yeah! I have changed navigation bar color that is showing on the fig as dark blue.

Comment: I mean about the other two that you're asking about, did you try any code? Or any changes in `XAML` that didn't work out for you?

Comment: Not i didn't make any changes.

Comment: @JINOSHAJI Link rot is a problem many on this site experience; a user will come along and post a link to their code.  Then someone will come by and answer the question, and eventually the OP's original source code will die off as the link disappears from the internet.  This is a problem for one real, main reason: future visitors to this website searching for the same problem will then come upon that question, and when they can't find the OP's original code so as to confirm they have the same problem, they'll be left without a solution.  So please; think of others and post your code.

Comment: @PaulKaram I have edited the question and updated it along with the code that i have done. If it is a valid question can you upvote and vote for reopen the question. If not please give the suggestions to improve this post. I have made a lot of changes into this question. So please review it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to maintain the color of Title bar through out the app then you can write the following code inside the `OnLaunched` in the App.xaml.cs within Xamarin.UWP client project. For more please refer to [Customizing Title Bar and Status Bar in Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](http://www.joeljoseph.net/customizing-title-bar-and-status-bar-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp/).

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView"))
{
    var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    if (titleBar != null)
    {
        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Red;
        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red;
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
    }
}
```

And if you want to custom tool bar background color, you could set the `BarBackgroundColor` of the `NavigationPage`. You can do something like the following code.

```
private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     ......   

     var nav = new NavigationPage();
     nav.PushAsync(page);
     nav.BarBackgroundColor = Color.MediumPurple;
     Detail = nav;

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I appreciate it. But one more thing in my case the hamburger button is not there. After navigating to another detail page by clicking on the items on Master area.How can i solve it

Comment: But it is ok for my first screen. but when i navigating to another detail page the hamburger button is not there.

Comment: Just refere my code uploded on Google drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2XtD2dQvEhzb1NnNGdydG91S0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please refer my code which is uploaded on google drive.Refer the following link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2XtD2dQvEhzb1NnNGdydG91S0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just try to navigate to another master detail page then see the thing

Comment: can you please send your email id then i can share my screenshot. and can you please share your screenshot of that window.

Comment: Yeah.. I have seen your screenshot. It's good.But I forgot to mention that i have made small changes after that the page is displayed as you mention. But now my problem is The Hamburger button and it's add stock title bar color. I can't change it.

Comment: In your example only one title bar is there but in my case two title bar is displaying like this.

Comment: I just want the 'Add Stock' title bar and it's background color as darkblue. I don't need master GST title bar

Comment: Now my question is updated. So I think now it is clear my exact requirement.